# Created a mongo atlas database and have successfully connected using nodejs. However, I get "dbItem is not defined" where dbItem is my database const

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

const uri =
 "mongodb+srv://username:1234321@cluster0.8imjcky.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
 try {
   const todolistDB = client.db("todolistDB");
   const dbItem = todolistDB.collection("Item");
  
   const defaultItems = [
     { item1: "welcome to your todolist" },
     { item2: "add new Item"},
     { item3: "delete item"}
   ];

const result = await dbItem.insertMany(defaultItems);
 console.log(`${result.insertedCount} documents were inserted`);
} finally {
 await client.close();
}
}
run().catch(console.dir);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  //const dbItem = app.locals.collection;
  dbItem.find({}, function(err, foundItems){
    res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
  });
```

This is the code I wrote to connect to my Mongo Atlas. The app connects to the atlas and the dbItem database has been created in atlas.

However, when try my run server in the terminal this error occurs: `ReferenceError: dbItem is not defined`

I also tried using `app.locals.collections = dbItem` just before the `app.get` function but that didnt work as well.

Answer (score 0):

`dbItem` is only in scope where it is created.  It this case, that is the run functions.  When that functions returns, `dbItem` falls out of scope and is garbage collected.

You might try declaring both `todolist` and `dbItem` at the same point as `client`